# 'TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'' finding the max. in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, max

Here, from a large data file split into different rows with the same 4th column. The third column represents mass, but it isn't always the largest value in the row. I'm trying to plot a line, with only the highest 10% of masses:

My code is as follows:

```
M1 = max(str(int(row1[i][2]))) #maximum value from row1, 3rd column
M2 = max(str(int(row2[j][2])))

if row1[i][2] >= M1*(0.1):
   plt.plot....
```

this gives me the error:

```
if row1[i][2] >= M1*float(0.1):
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

My rows look like this (each row on separate line):

```
[[1, -1, 10, 0]]
[[2, 1, 2, 19]]
[[3, 2, 15, 20], [4, 2, 50, 20], [5, 2, 90, 20]]
[[6, 3, 15, 21]]
[[7, 4, 50, 40]]
[[8, 5, 90, 50]]
[[9, 6, 13, 60]]
[[10, 7, 50, 65]]
[[11, 8, 70, 74], [12, 8, 95, 74], [13, 8, 75, 74]].....
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance

Comment: M1 and M2 are strings. Remove the str() statement

Comment: @alex314159 this goes on to give me the error `    M1 = max(int(row1[i][2]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: M1 = int(max(row1[i][2])) should do the trick.

Comment: Technically, might not be a duplicate, but you've pasted almost the whole question, and hidden the small difference from the last question so people will be answering the title question, not your specific modification.

Answer (score 1):

When giving `row1[i][2]` you are giving a single number, but max takes a list

so alex314159 is right, you should remove the `str()`

what you can put is:

```
int(max(row1[i]))
```